# How do the works attributed to Aristotle are determined to originate from him?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Are there other surviving works that were written at around the same time as Aristotle's that cite the works or concepts from the Aristotelian corpus?

Comment: Tradition of scholarly ancient works. There are also works attributed to A but later considered not original. See e.g.  [Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanics_(Aristotle))

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what are the earliest works that refer to the aristotelian corpus as it is known today?

Comment: or *Brill’s Companion to the Reception of Aristotle in Antiquity*, ed.
A Falcon, 2016

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Please do not answer in comments